# Counting the number of first place scores with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, so I have the following database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `highscores` (
  `lid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`lid`,`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

lid being the level id.

lets say I have the following values in the table:

```
lid, username,score

1,sam,15 
1,joe,12
1,sue,6
1,josh,9
2,sam,8
2,joe,16 
2,sue,4
3,sam,65 
4,josh,87 
4,sue,43
5,sam,12
5,sue,28
5,joe,29
and so on.
```

How would I create a query(or if required a set of queries) to get the following

```
sam has 3 high scores
joe has 2 high scores
josh has 1 high score
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you  define "high score"?

Comment: high score is the best score(largest score) for a single level.  I want to make a leaderboard that counts the total number of first places that username has. I have tried a using a mix of count(score) and grouping, but i'm not all that great with mysql, so I was not getting any good results, or getting an error.

Comment: I have considered a "best score" bool column, but is that the best way to do it?

Comment: It was nice to see a description of the table structure. I wish more questions included them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have not tested it, but try the following query

```
select 
    concat(h.username ," has ", count(h.username)," high scores ")
from
    highscores h inner join
    (select lid, max(score) as maxscore
     from highscores group by lid) t on h.lid = t.lid and h.score = t.maxscore
group by h.username
```

Comment: This one runs even faster then liqorvicars. Thank you as well. Also, thanks for reformatting my question

Comment: You'll benefit from a `(lid, score)` index. But this answer, with Join, is probably the faster one.

Comment: fantastic. after adding the index query time went from .0996 to .0436. Table currently has 21,000+ rows.

Answer (score 2):

From what you've described this query will produce what you need

```
SELECT username,COUNT(*) as num_highscores FROM (
SELECT lid,username
FROM highscores h1
WHERE score=(
    SELECT MAX(score) 
    FROM highscores h2 
    WHERE h2.lid=h1.lid
)
) AS high_scores
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY num_highscores DESC
```

Although the results I get on your sample data are different:

- sam  2
- joe  2
- josh 1

Comment: Wow! works like a charm! thank you so much for your help. This community is fantastic .